# How to choose embossing color?

Tags: website-design, color, text

I'm using css to emboss text with this:

```
text-shadow: black 1px 1px 5px;
```

My site uses different font colors and background colors. I was wondering how I can choose the "best" embossing color based on the color of the font and background color of the text.

Comment: Can you include a visual example of what you have now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to replicate blind embossing (no ink) then the text color would match the the background. Give a dark SE shadow and a white NW shadow to give it a raised effect.

Otherwise, the text color can be whatever you want provided it's darker than your dark shadow and lighter than your highlight 'shadow'.